# How do I pattern match with Data.Text in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am currently in the process of writing a parser in Haskell. I have the following code.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.Text

newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: Text -> Either Text (Text, a) }

char1 :: Char -> Parser Char
char1 c = Parser $ \case
    (x:xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
    _               -> Left "Unexpected character"
```

It fails to compile with these two errors.

```
test.hs:12:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    • In the pattern: x : xs
      In a case alternative: (x : xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\case
           (x : xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
           _ -> Left "Unexpected character"’
   |
12 |     (x:xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
   |      ^^^^

test.hs:12:24: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Text’
      Expected type: Either Text (Text, Char)
        Actual type: Either Text ([Char], Char)
    • In the expression: Right (xs, x)
      In a case alternative: (x : xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\case
           (x : xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
           _ -> Left "Unexpected character"’
   |
12 |     (x:xs) | x == c -> Right (xs, x)
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can fix the error by replacing the `Text` data type with `String` but I would prefer to use the `Text` data type.

Is there a way to pattern match with the `Data.Text` type without first explicitly converting it to a string first? Perhaps there is a GHC extension that would allow me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match on a call to [`uncons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.4.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:uncons).

```
case uncons text of
    Just (x, xs) -> ...
    Nothing -> ...
```

View patterns let you do this within the pattern instead of within the scrutinee, but require you to say `uncons` once for each pattern.

```
case text of
    (uncons -> Just (x, xs)) -> ...
    (uncons -> Nothing) -> ...
```

Comment: there's no requirement. you could use `_`  as the second pattern (or any regular pattern as applicable). having mutually exclusive patterns can be seen as a matter of good style, of course.

Answer (score 7):

A a refinement to @DanielWagner's answer, you can combine view patterns and pattern synonyms to do this.  You'll need a new constructor in place of `:`, but it might look like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Text

pattern x :> xs <- (uncons -> Just (x, xs))
pattern Empty <- (uncons -> Nothing)

findInText :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Maybe Char
findInText _ Empty = Nothing
findInText p (x :> xs) | p x = Just x
                       | otherwise = findInText p xs
```

The idea here is that a pattern `x :> xs` is a synonym for the pattern `uncons -> Just (x, xs)` which is a view pattern that operates by applying `uncons` to the scrutinee and pattern-matching the result with `Just (x, xs)` to population `x` and `xs` for the parent pattern.

As per the comment, there might be some concern about whether this usage ends up calling `uncons` more than once.  With optimization entirely shut off (`-O0`), the generated core *does* have multiple `uncons` calls:

```
-- unoptimized -O0
findInText
  = \ ds ds1 ->
      case uncons ds1 of {
        Nothing -> Nothing;
        Just ipv ->
          case uncons ds1 of {
            Nothing -> ...
```

With optimization on (`-O` or `-O2`), everything gets inlined and the generated core is incredibly complicated because of the Unicode processing going on.  However, if you also define:

```
findInText' :: (Char -> Bool) -> Text -> Maybe Char
findInText' p txt = case uncons txt of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just (x, xs) | p x -> Just x
               | otherwise -> findInText' p xs
```

it turns out that GHC compiles `findInText'` to:

```
findInText' = findInText
```

so it looks like in this case at least, GHC doesn't do any extra work as a result of the view patterns.

Comment: Beautiful. One hesitation I had, even with the visible view patterns in my answer: is GHC smart enough to call `uncons` just once, even if I use both patterns?